# Why I get a parse error on a visibility property despite I work with PHP 7.4?

Tags: php

I made a class with this line:

```
public string $email;
```

And I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) ... on line 4
```

A `php -v` command give me

```
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2020 11:52:41) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

I work on a Wampserver.

Answer (score 1):

`php -v` give me information about a version installed on my computer, but Wampserver used a PHP 7.3.21 version.
I set Wampserver on PHP 7.4.9 and everything is fine now.